# How to optimize LAN connection between two home computers

Tags: home-networking, lan, network-adapter, speedtest

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize the connection between my home computers.

Both have Intel CT Gigabit PCI-e network adapters using Jumbo packets, etc (both PCs are setup the same). I'm using a standard Netgear 8-port switch.

**Is there a specific tool that can check and optimize the connection?**
**Or is there something else I can check in the NIC settings besides Jumbo packets?**

Why optimize? I still find a transfer rate of 20-30MB/s (not always but sometimes) is a little on the low end, and sometimes when playing (even non-HD) videos I experience lags. I understand the causes for this can be anything, but I'm still interested in optimizing the LAN connection.

Since both computers have two Intel NICs each, how would teaming them help in any way? Has any one tried that before?

Thanks!

Comment: What Model of Switch are you using? 30MB/s is very slow for Gigabit. But then it depends also on what exactly you're doing.
I often use Socket Test but it does no longer seem to ba available anymore. Maybe http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/ is the follow up to what I use... Edit: No, it isn't, mine certainly is not using Java

Comment: You need to test independently of other hardware, as disk space could be a limiting factor, or if you are streaming, decoding.  If you are on linux, then iperf is a good utility for assessing network throughput.  However, 30MB is plenty fast enough for non-HD video, so it must be something other than raw speed.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware big influence to transfer has also speed of you hard disks which usually decrease performance quite much. I suggest using SSD's, but they are so expensive. If you would use wifi you can manage QoS [WMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions). I think it has to be also possible in LAN if you would have more inteligent switch -> usually costs more money. One more addition: use [CAT6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable) cables in 1GE

Comment: thanks. I use SSDs on both ends and CAT6 cables. I didn't know that a HDD running low on space could slow down the connection. Thanks!